# New to VBA, Assigning each location a designated number of buildings In two different spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I’m really new to VBA and especially programming in general but I know the absolute basics just from experience with excel formulas. Would love some help and guidance.

So in spreadsheet 1 I have a long list of locations, think thousands. In spreadsheet 2 we have a list of buildings that can be assigned to each location in order with column A having their name and column B the building number for the location.

Usually with dealing with something like this I would just use a macro to copy past each building to pair it with a location, but in this problem I could potentially have multiple buildings for each location. 
As a small example

Worksheet 1

```
Location 1 
Location 2 
Location 3
```

Worksheet 2

```
A Column  |  B column 
Building  |  1
Building  |  1
Building  |  2
Building  |  3
Building  |  1
Building  |  2
```

How I would need it to end up would be:

```
Location 1
Building 1

Location 2
Building 1
Building 2 
Building 3

Location 3
Building 1
Building 2
```

This is where I am now. I'm trying to use something I gathered from somewhere else to hopefully tailor to my needs

```
Dim c As Range
    i As Integer
    j As Integer
    i = 0
 For Each c In Range(“B2:B80462”)

If c = 1 Then
  Cells(2 + i, 6) = Cells(c.Row, c.Column - 1)
  Cells(2 + i, 7) = c
Else
    If c = 2 Then
      Cells(2 + i + (C - 1), 6) = Cells(c.Row, c.Column 0)
      Cells(2 + i + (C - 1), 7) = c
```

Etc. for potentially up to 12 buildings per location and loop that

I also created space in Worksheet A to hopefully fit it in there with this:

```
Do Untill IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
Selection.Insert Shift:=x1Down
Selection.Insert Shift:=x1Down
Selection.Insert Shift:=x1Down
Selection.Insert Shift:=x1Down
Selection.offset(5, 0 ).Select
Loop
```

and run that 3 times to get the space for the potential 12 buildings

Am I close?

Comment: worksheet 2 / column A seems to have been truncated...  Also there is no rule which assigns sheets 1 & 2 into a set.

Answer (score 0):

This code will store all the locations in sheet 2 along with all their buildings and then paste them to the sheet1 like  a list.

Tested and worked:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()

    Dim Locations As Object
    Set Locations = GetLocationsForEachBuilding

    CreateListOfLocations Locations

End Sub
Function GetLocationsForEachBuilding() As Object

    'Find the range for your buildings/location worksheet and insert them into an array
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet2") 'change this

        'Last row for your range
        Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'Insert the range into an array
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = .Range("A2:B" & lrow).Value

    End With

    'Create a dictionary which will hold every location with all their buildings separated by "_"
    Dim Dict As Object: Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Loop through the array to get all the locations with their buildings
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not Dict.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
            Dict.Add arr(i, 2), arr(i, 1)
        Else
            'The "_" is the delimitator, change it if your buildings have this on the name
            Dict(arr(i, 2)) = Dict(arr(i, 2)) & "_" & arr(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    Erase arr

    Set GetLocationsForEachBuilding = Dict

End Function
Sub CreateListOfLocations(Locations As Object)

    'Let's first calculate the large of our array
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim MyCounter As Long
    For Each Item In Locations.Items
        MySplit = Split(Item, "_")
        MyCounter = MyCounter + UBound(MySplit) + 1
    Next Item

    'Dimension an array with the large of the locations
    ReDim arr(1 To MyCounter + Locations.Count) As String

    'Now drop all the data on your new array
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim x As Long
    For Each Key In Locations.Keys
        arr(i) = Key 'the location name
        i = i + 1 'add a row
        MySplit = Split(Locations(Key), "_") 'split your buildings with "_"
        For x = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit) 'loop through all the buildings in the location
            arr(i) = MySplit(x) 'the building
            i = i + 1 'add a row
        Next x
    Next Key

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourFirstSheet") 'change this
        .Cells.Delete 'this will delete all your cells on that sheet
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr) 'paste the array to the worksheet
    End With

End Sub
```

Change the sheet names to yours.